# Auto download images from website with multiple urls

Tags: vba, url, imagedownload

I want to be able to download images by using multiple image urls on vba. This is the code I have right now, and everytime I try download, it fails (It reads "Files not Found!"). Any help will be appreciated!!!

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long


Private Sub Image()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim url As String
    Dim done As Long
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        For i = 1 To 4
       url = Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Text
    done = URLDownloadToFile(0, url, "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\", 0, 0)

      Next
        'Test.
        If done = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Files have been downloaded!"
        Else
            MsgBox "Files not Found!"
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `done`? What error code does it reference?

Comment: done = URLDownloadToFile(0, url, "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\", 0, 0)
This references to see if the file has been downloaded or not

Comment: Also, are your URLs valid after they are loaded into the `url` variable? There's a lot of debugging you need to do.

Comment: Post some sample `url` values

Answer (score 0):

I have got this code to work by doing two simple things:

Make sure you have http:// included in your urls, without the http URLDownloadToFile fails to download the file.

The usage of the URLDownloadToFile function is expecting a filename rather than a path name for the downloaded file.  A quick and dirty fix is to do the following:

```
done = URLDownloadToFile(0, url, "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\pic" & i & ".gif", 0, 0)
```

which assigns a name to each file using i.

A better solution would parse the filename from the url and save using this filename.

Other than that the code worked fine for me.